# Select editor programmatically

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jface

I have written an Eclpse plugin that contains several editor types. For each editor a content type is associated. In some situations I have two possible editors for the same contenttype. I know that I can select the editor via "Open with". But I would like to decide automatically which editor should be opened.

Here is an example
In one plugins I have got the following extension point definitions:

```xml
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.editors">
      <editor
            class="de.dstg.adsplus.editors.program.MacroEditor"
         contributorClass="de.dstg.adsplus.editors.core.ADSTextEditorActionContributor"
            default="true"
            icon="icons/macro.png"
            id="de.dstg.adsplus.editors.editors.macroEditor"
            name="ADS Macro Editor">
         <contentTypeBinding
               contentTypeId="de.dstg.adsplus.macro">
         </contentTypeBinding>
      </editor>
  </extension
```

In another plugin I have this definiton:

```xml
  <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.editors">
      <editor
            class="de.dstg.adsplus.focusededitor.FocusedEditor"
            contributorClass="de.dstg.adsplus.focusededitor.FocusedEditorContributor"
            icon="icons/dveditor.png"
            id="de.dstg.adsplus.focusededitor"
            name="ADS Focused Editor">
         <contentTypeBinding
               contentTypeId="de.dstg.adsplus.macro">
         </contentTypeBinding>
```

When I double click on a file with this content type I would like to decide programmatically which editor to open depending on the content of the file or the location where it is stored.
I have tried to find a method that I could implement but without success.

Answer (score 0):

You could use two different content types both using the same file extensions and use a 'content type describer' to distinguish the files.

The content type describer is defined in the content type extension point:

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.core.contenttype.contentTypes"> 
   <content-type id="ABC"
      base-type="org.eclipse.core.runtime.xml"      
      file-extensions="a,b,c">
    <describer class="org.eclipse.core.runtime.content.XMLRootElementContentDescriber2">
    </describer>
  </content-type>
```

The content describer class implements `IContentDescriber` or `ITextContentDescriber`. Eclipse calls the `describe` method to find out if the file is valid for the content type (and to get information about other attributes of the file).

Comment: Thanks Greg, maybe I will try this. I wanted to avoid to add a new content type because I am using the content types in several places within my plugins and a new content types means that I would have to change the code there too.